# Overlapping Text on Stack Overflow comments

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, comments, design, sidebar

I was just reading through some comments on [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) and noticed the comments overlap the right-sidebar links slightly.

[image]

Comment: What browser and operating system are you using? I'm not seeing this on Chrome/Mac.